# Find a pointwise convergent subsequence of a pointwise bounded sequence without use of the diagonal process

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a pointwise bounded sequence of complex-valued functions defined on a countable set $E$.

> Arrange the points of $E$ into a sequence $\{p_n\}$.
> Since $\{f_n(p_1)\}$ is a bounded sequence of complex numbers, we can find a subsequence $\{f^{(1)}_n\}$ of $\{f_n\}$ such that $\{f^{(1)}_n(p_1)\}$ converges. Since $\{f^{(1)}_n(p_2)\}$ is a bounded sequence of complex numbers, we can find a subsequence $\{f^{(2)}_n\}$ of $\{f^{(1)}_n\}$ such that $\{f^{(2)}_n(p_2)\}$ converges. Notice that $\{f^{(2)}_n(p_1)\}$ also converges. Continuing in this fashion, we obtain a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ of $\{f_n\}$ such that $\{f_{n_k}(p_m)\}$ converges for each $m$.

What's wrong with this argument?

Comment: If you just mention that the subsequence is defined by $f_{n_k}=f_k^{(k)}$ (the diagonal subsequence) then the argument is fine.

Comment: You have defined a sequence of sequences, but it still remains to define $(f_{n_k})$. That is where the diagonal process is used.

Comment: The issue is you never defined $f_{n_k}$

Comment: To be explicit, I didn't define $f_{n_k}$ as $f^{(k)}_k$. I just say that there is a list of subsequences such that $\{f_n\}\supset\{f^{(1)}_n\}\supset\{f^{(2)}_n\}\supset\cdots$. The "limit" of this list is $\{f_{n_k}\}$. So this is wrong because it is not clear at all what $\{f_{n_k}\}$ is?

Comment: The limit of the sequence of sequences? It is still not clear exactly what $f_{n_k}$ is.

Comment: The intersection of nested sets need not be a sequence, even if each intermediate set is a sequence.  There is a broader issue with your post.  The problem is framed (set up and goal) only in the title, something that invites the sort of omission that occurs in your write-up of a solution.  A good practice is to begin the body of the Question with the set up and goal of the problem and use following paragraphs to provide context (such as your attempted solution, etc.).